# Python script crashes when fail to connect to server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm testing my Python script and when server turned off my script crashes. How can I change this, to make connection again. Now, my script is crashing when it fails to connect to the server. Here is my script:

```
import urllib.request
import json


def connectToServer():
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:5000/user/connect") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Here is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\Hacker_Pro Python\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    server.connectToServer()
  File "e:\Projects\Hacker_Pro Python\server.py", line 8, in connectToServer
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:5000/user/connect") as url:
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1375, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\Rostik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Sorry I forget to add the error stack. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The python [try statement](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) may help you.

```
def connectToServer():
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:5000/user/connect") as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    except ConnectionRefusedError as error:
        print('connection was refused:\n{}'.format(error))

    except:
        print('could not connect to server')
```

Comment: Never use `except:`. If you need to catch all regular expressions, `except Exception:`.

Comment: As I understand it, `except Exception:` only makes it so that you can reference the exception in the statement, which can be very helpful.  Sometimes, though, it is perfectly acceptable to print a readable statement about what failed, rather than focusing on why it failed.  Am I missing a legitimate reason to "never" use `except:` ?